# R {shape} Avoid dashed edge of "triangle" arrow when using dashed line type?

Tags: r, plot

I really enjoy the basic R plotting and I've recently discovered different arrowhead types in {shape} package. However, using dashed line (lty = 3), the edge of my arrowhead is "dashed" and not smooth as I expect. Is there a way how to keep my edge smooth but my line dashed?

Thanks!

```
library(shape)
plot(c(0,2),c(-2,2), col=NA)
Arrows(c(0,1.7),c(1.3,-1.8),c(0.8,1.1),c(1.2,-1), lwd=2, lty = 3, arr.type = "triangle", arr.adj = 0.5, arr.col = "black", arr.length = 0.4, arr.width = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see an `arr.lty` parameter which would make sense, so you could use `segments` to plot the dotted line and use `Arrows` just for the arrowhead but that's not really ideal

Comment: thanks @Jota !! would you like to post it as the answer as I can accept it? works fine ! ;)

Comment: thanks @rawr for suggestions ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
plot(c(0,2), c(-2,2), col = NA)
Arrows(c(0,1.7), c(1.3,-1.8), c(0.8,1.1), c(1.2,-1),
  lwd = 2, lty = 3, arr.width = 0, arr.length = 0)
```

to get the line with no arrow, then add the arrow using your existing call with the addition of the `lcol = "transparent"` argument to plot the arrow without the line showing up.

```
Arrows(c(0,1.7), c(1.3,-1.8), c(0.8,1.1), c(1.2,-1),
  lwd = 2, lty = 3, arr.type = "triangle", arr.adj = 0.5,
  arr.col = "black", arr.length = 0.4, arr.width = 0.3,
  lcol = "transparent")
```